# useState cannot change boolean value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a project, in which clicking on a specific word in a paragraph opens/closes a component `<Overlay/>` which contains a child component: `<Modal />`. A close button is inside the `Modal` and is attached to a callback function. I tried to use `useState` and set a `boolean` value hidden between `true` and `false` to handle this case, but it seems the `setHidden` function doesn't work.

My partial code is here:

```
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  const { renderOverlay } = getOverlay();
  const openModal = text => (
    <h1
      onClick={() => {
        openOverlay();
      }}
    >
      {`${text}`}
    </h1>
  );

  const closeModal = () => {
    setHidden(true);
    console.log(hidden); // false
  };

  const openOverlay = () => {
    !hidden
      ? renderOverlay(
        <Modal
              title="ABCDE"
              message="
        You must be a member of  to access the app
        "
              close={{ onClose: closeModal, text: 'Close' }}
          />
        )
      : renderOverlay();
  };
  return (
          <span
            className={paragraph.style === 'bold' ? 'boldspan' : null}
            key={paragraph.paragraphKey}
            style={{ color: paragraph.color }}
          >
            {paragraph.isLink ? openModal(paragraph.text) : paragraph.text + addSpace}
            {paragraph.break ? <br /> : null}
          </span>
        );
```

Modal:

```
export default function Modal({ title, message, close, route }) {
  return (
    <ModalStyles>
      <div className="top__border" />
      <div className="content">
        <span className="title">{title}</span>
        <span className="message">{message}</span>
        <div className="button__group">
          {close && <Button type="primary" text={close.text} onClick={close.onClose} />}
          {route && <Button type="primary" text={route.text} onClick={route.onRoute} />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </ModalStyles>
  );
}
```

Does anyone know why I cannot change the `hidden` property in the `closeModal` function?

Comment: Your function openOverlay doesn't do anything. Just because it returns some jsx doesn't mean it will render. Only whatever you return inside your return () will render.

Comment: You should learn more about how to write declarative ui components. Your component is not declarative, besides my first point.

Comment: @FurkanO, thank you for you comments. I follow your hint and figure out the issue